# flutter write firebase storage download url to firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

in my flutter app i'm looping through a list of image files and uploading it to firebase storage. after that i'm uploading that download url and other fields to firestore. but when upload completes it creates multiple docs as the same length as the image list.

```
void _addImages() {
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    widget.images.forEach((img) async {
      String imageName = img
          .toString()
          .substring(
              img.toString().lastIndexOf("/"), img.toString().lastIndexOf("."))
          .replaceAll("/", "");

      String path = img.toString().substring(
          img.toString().indexOf("/") + 1, img.toString().lastIndexOf("/"));

      final uuid = Uuid();

      TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await storage
          .ref('posts/${auth.currentUser!.email!}/${uuid.v1()}/$imageName')
          .putFile(img!);
      final List<String> downloadUrl = [
        await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
      ];

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").add({
          "url": downloadUrl,
          "caption": _captionController.text,
          "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          "postType": "image",
          "isAdvert": false,
          "webLink": null,
          "blocked": false,
          "advertType": null,
          "email": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
        });

        Get.to(HomePage());
    });
  }
```

I know i'm uploading to firestore inside of the `forEach` method. but i did that in order to get the download url. ever since flutter 2.0 the late keyword has been a headache.

```
if (downloadUrl.length == widget.images.length) {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").add({
          "url": downloadUrl,
          "caption": _captionController.text,
          "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          "postType": "image",
          "isAdvert": false,
          "webLink": null,
          "blocked": false,
          "advertType": null,
          "email": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
        });

        Get.to(HomePage());
      }
```

i even tried to wrap it inside if condition, but it still doesn't work. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter upload file to firebase storage and firestore not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75781196/flutter-upload-file-to-firebase-storage-and-firestore-not-working-correctly)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya that's my question as well